# XACML selected role authorization example - XACML for RBAC

Tags: wso2, xacml, entitlements, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server with XACML for authorization.

I have users with serveral roles in IS. The user must select one of them to enter the app. So I need to grant the user based only in one of all his roles.

I used `port.getDecisionByAttributes(subject, resource, action, environment);` of the ***EntitlementService*** for asking with SOAP WS to the policy defined in XACML. The subject is the username. But It grants because it uses all user's roles.

Example:

- User: **peter**
- Roles: **rolegranted**, **rolenotgranted**, otherrole

When **peter** enter the app and select **rolenotgranted** it should **not access** the resource.

When **peter** enter the app and select **rolegranted** it should **access** the resource.

How do I define de XACML policy? and which method of the EntitlementService should I use?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had met the requirements passing the role in the subject arg of the getDecisionByAttributes method. WSO2 IS doesn't check if this subject exists, so I can pass anything here and test it in the policy rule.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,  you need to write role based XACML policies in the PDP.  Entitlement service method that you are using is fine.  You can send the username in the XACML request and verify the user's roles using user store (via PIP),  I would like to suggest you to go through [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/11/30/implementing-rbac-and-abac-with-xacml/) blog.  It explain how you can write a role based XACML policy in WSO2IS and use it property.